# How to find the lightest object

Tags: javascript, oop

How can I find the lightest object from array of objects? I do not want to get value, but the object with this value. Not for instance just 1200 but the object {`mass: 1200, numberOfel: ..., indexOfEl: ... , isCorrect: boolean}`

```
let massOfElephants = [2400, 2000, 1200, 2400, 1600, 4000];
let startOrder = [1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2];
const elephantObject = [];
  
  startOrder.forEach((val, i) => {
    elephantObject.push({
      mass: massOfElephants[val - 1],
      numberOfEl: val,
      indexOfEl: i,
      isCorrect: false,
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduce method reduces an array to a single value using a callback function.

```
const getLightest = (initial, current){
    return (initial.mass < current.mass)?initial:current;
}
const lightest = elephantObject.reduce(getLightest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a list of objects already, all you need to do is sort the objects according to their `mass` properties. The way to go about it is to write a custom comparator function which to sort by (See [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)).

For numeric types, the comparator function `(a,b) => a - b` will sort the values increasingly, and `myArray.sort((a, b) => a - b)` will sort `myArray` accordingly.

After sorting `elephantObject.sort((a,b) => a.mass - b.mass)`, the lightest elephant will be the first entry of your object array: `elephantObject[0]`.
as